# Undefined variable when checking if variable is defined in Kohana view

Tags: php

I'm running into this error when loading up my view:

> ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: errors
>   APPPATH\views\admin\category\add.php [ 2 ]

```
<h3>Add</h3>  
<?php if( $errors ): ?>
<p><?=$errors?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How is my checking not valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to give this one a try:

[isset Manual](http://php.net/isset)

or you can actually show the controller code in which you're failing to set the errors to the View object (probably inside of a condition).

Comment: Please delete this answer so I can delete this question. This is embarrassing :(

Comment: and now there are 3 more answers. I'd remove myself from SO :P

Comment: @gAMBOOKa don't feel bad about it.  We all make dumb ass errors sometimes.  Just do a little more research in future and triple check code before jumping on SO to ask :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Kemo said you should use isset.  What you are actually doing there is checking if the variable `$errors` has a value that evaluates to true/false.  The non-existence of the variable does not equate to false and you wouldn't want it to, you want spelling mistakes etc... to throw errors rather than any variable just being considered null regardless of whether it's actually been declared.  `isset` is specifically designed to check for the existence of the variable.  As you still want to check if it also evaluates to true you should be doing:

```
if(isset($errors) && $errors)
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. It makes sense when you say checking for `$errors` is basically basically requesting a true / false response to the condition.

Answer (score 0):

An undefined variable means it does not exists. You can just wrap it inside [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to do what you want to do:

```
<?php if( isset( $errors ) ): ?>
```

Isset is one of the few language constructs that work on unset variables without giving a warning / error. Another one is [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty).

Answer (score -2):

PHP is throwing an error because the error reporting includes the E_STRICT constant, which throws an exception if an undefined variable is pointed to.

Use [isset()](http://php.net/isset) instead - It's good practice to check if your variable even exists (if there's a chance that it doesn't).